# How to create a less specified timeline diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, linguistics

I want to use Latex to create Kleinian tense/aspect diagrams like the ones below. I've tried looking at timeline code, but they tend to be too complicated for my purposes or include years/time measurements, which I don't need. I only need to be able to label certain points (t0/ts below) and spans (t' and tE below). Should I use TikZ? New to Latex and trying to do this the easy way. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Please see the comments in the link below—https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666833/how-to-draw-the-following-number-line-in-latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? This site is not service for "do-this-for-me" ...

Comment: @Margaret Request see if the answer below meet your requirements-in case please accept the answer by clicking the green check mark on the left side of the answer

Answer (score 2):

I have drawn the first figure with explanatory comments - you should be able to take it forward from here- please upload a minimum working example (MWE)as explained on the website whenever you ask a question - this will attract a larger audience for help

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (12,0) node (b) {} ;%draws a horizontal line
        \foreach \x [count=\i] in {1,2,...,5}%
        {
            \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*2,-2mm) node[](n\i) {} -- ++(0,4mm);%draws the five ticks in the horizontal line
        }
            \draw[%draws the brace on the underside
                        decorate, 
                        decoration={%
                                            brace, 
                                            amplitude=6pt}]%
                                            ([yshift=-1em]n4.south)--
                                             node[below=0.25cm]{\texttt{\tiny \makecell{${t_E}$\\reading a book}}}
                                            ([yshift=-1em]n1.south);
            \draw[%draws the upper brace
                        decorate, 
                        decoration={%
                                            brace, 
                                            amplitude=6pt}]%
                                            ([yshift=1em]n2.north)--
                                            node[above=0.25cm]{\texttt{\tiny \makecell{${t'}$\\yesterday}}}
                                            ([yshift=1em]n3.north);
            \node[above=2em of n5] (n6) {${t^0/t^s}$};% for the suffix over the fifth tick
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]